# I have two Text areas and I need the text area2 to display the values I type in text area1

Tags: javascript, html

**If I try to write in Text area1, the values should be displayed in text area1 and text area2. Is there a simple way for that?
Its working in a normal textarea. I need to add a text editor, I tried ck editor for that, When i Use strong text editor as a script src, the function is not working.**

Answer (score 1):

Use onkeyup and call a function which will copy the values

```js
function a(){
document.getElementById("a2").value=document.getElementById("a1").value
}
```

```html
<textarea id="a1" onkeyup="a()"></textarea>
<textarea id="a2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Its working in a normal textarea. I need to add a text editor in the text area1, for Font face, size and lists, I tried ck editor for that, When i Use CK editor as a script src, the function is not working.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function populateSecondTextBox() {
    document.getElementById('txtSecond').value = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
}
```

```html
<p>Write Here :
    <textarea id="txtFirst" onkeyup="populateSecondTextBox();"></textarea>
</p>
<p>Will be coiped here :
   
<textarea id="txtSecond"></textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Its working in a normal textarea. I need to add a text editor in the text area1, for Font face, size and lists, I tried ck editor for that, When i Use CK editor as a script src, the function is not working.